# Why do you need to specify a site when getting the inbox?

Tags: discussion, api, inbox

I'm getting a user's inbox via [/me/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox). I am forced to specify a site with this, so I'm setting it to Stack Overflow. However, it still gets all my notifications, including those from other sites. What is the point of having to specify a site if it makes no difference in the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) instead, which is a network route instead of a site-specific one. As [mentioned in the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox), the site-specific route is mostly just provided for convenience of consumers working in a single-site context.

Even then it doesn't seem particularly useful, but meh. To answer your question in regards to why site is required there, it's because [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) routes just substitute in the authed user ID for the request's user ID parameter, and that requires a site (since it's not the global account ID). This makes more sense for the other [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) routes than it does this one, of course.

Comment: The more I look into this, the more it seems it's a bug. and other `/me/*` routes do not require a site parameter. (`/me/associated` and `/me/merges`, for example)

Comment: Those are network routes, though. This exists explicitly as a site-specific route that duplicates `/inbox`'s functionality. I don't think there's a good reason for the route to exist in the first place, but the behaviour is at least intentional.

Comment: This is a network route that is improperly treated as a site-specific route for no good reason that I can see (inbox is network-wide).  Especially since we have `/me` routes in both categories.  ... Also, the /me routes that take `site` need to document why in cases like this.  The only helpful clues are not on [the applicable doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox).

Comment: The only reason the route exists is so that applications which always append `site` don't get an error trying to invoke the network-based `/inbox`, which rejects that parameter. Laziness is literally the only purpose for this route, and people should always use `/inbox`.

Comment: Totally hijacking this comment thread, but I'm not aware of any other way to get a hold of a mod; @TimStone any chance I could get you to send me a "moderator message"? I'm trying to test all types of notifications (each uses its own icon, etc.) in my app.