# Why is the `site` parameter required in `/me` call?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, documentation

I want to query information about the logged-in user using [me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me), and this `site` parameter is creating some small problems.
I am developing a visual studio extension where upon logging in a user will get all his network accounts using [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users). After that, on clicking on any of the associated account, he will get more information about the user in that site, eg, stackoverflow, using [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me). In this step, there is a parameter `site`. So how to have the parameter `site` where the user have accounts, so that I will pass it to [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me)?

1. On what basis is the `site` parameter present? Is it the `api_site_parameter` of [site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site)?
2. It would be better if this parameter wasn't present. Then, it would return a list of [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) in every site. This would make [me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) independent of `site`.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.  State your ultimate purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE:

1. Is `site` the `api_site_parameter` of the site object?
   **Yes.**   Although as stated in the "Per-Site Methods" [section of the main doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs#tabs), you can also use the full domain name, EG `cooking.stackexchange.com`.
2. No, [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) and [shallow_user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) **are site specific objects**.  You absolutely need to specify `site` to get these.

---

**Supposedly, [the assumption is that all `/me` routes are site specific](https://stackapps.com/a/6769/7653) -- used by apps that only focus on one domain.**

As stated in the "Users" section of [the main doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs):

> All user methods that take an `{ids}` parameter have a `/me` equivalent method that takes an `access_token` instead.
>   These methods are **provided for developer convenience**, with the exception of plain /me, which is actually necessary for discovering which user authenticated to an application.

Buried in [2 or 3 particular doc pages](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-inbox) it states:

> {These methods are} provided for consumers who make strong assumptions about operating within the context of a single site rather than the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

Where the applicable routes are of the form `/users/{id}/{Some SE-wide object}` and by implication this would include the `/me/{Some SE-wide object}` routes.

This certainly **should be better documented** in the pages where this doesn't make sense (EG: [`/me`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me), 
[`/me/notifications`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-notifications), 
[`/me/inbox`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox), and 
[`/me/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-inbox)).

And note that **other `/me/` routes, like [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) and [/me/merges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-merge-history), do not require a `site` parameter.**

---

## What is your true purpose?

The question is unclear.

- **To get the user's Stack Exchange-wide id**, use [the `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens):

  ```
  "account_id": 131474,
  "expires_on_date": 1455815636,
  "access_token": "3OT6bxxxxxxxxxxqPMZK9Q))"
  ```
- **To get all of the user's associated accounts**, use [the `/me/associated` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users):

  ```
  {
      "user_id": 331508,
      "site_name": "Stack Overflow"
  }, {
      "user_id": 55814,
      "site_name": "Server Fault"
  }, {
      "user_id": 41023,
      "site_name": "Super User"
  },
  etc.
  ```

Comment: Your 2 points answered my question.  Sending full domain name like "stackoverflow.com" which is returned as `site_url` from [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) solved my problem. Thanks.